# How to position text in html with div tags?

Tags: css, html

This code:

```
  <div id="columns">
        text
    </div>
    <div id="columns">
        text
    </div>
    <div id="columns">
        text
    </div>
```

Is coded with this css:

```
   #columns {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
```

The problem is that if I put any text below the three columns created, it just adds another column! I want the footer to be below these columns, but I can only do this so far by setting this:

```
footer {
    /*height: 50px;*/
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

And this just makes the page longer, i.e. puts a huge gap between this content and the footer.
Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: um, has no one mentioned that there are three divs all with the same id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements are floated left making document flow modified. Document flow needs to be reset right before writing footer. It can be done by setting property `clear:both` for the footer (in fact just after `.columns` are finished).

A working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaranjan/84Xvk/) is here.

CSS:

```
footer{
    clear: both;
}
```

*Suggestion (outside scope of question):
You should change `id="columns"` to `class="columns"` as in valid html markup, id's should be unique. (thanks michael)*

Comment: the issue is that the same id is being used for three div elements. By changing this id to a class, the code will work fine without clearing the footer.

Comment: changing id to class is a great suggestion to fix the markup (i didn't even notice that on first glance). however doing that will not fix position of footer, unless we clear the document flow. i just ran a quick check at http://jsfiddle.net/priyaranjan/84Xvk/1/

Comment: right, makes sense. if you change the ids to classes in your answer, you've got the correct one

Answer (score 0):

try this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zX8DW/)**

**css**

```
   *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    #columns {
            width: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: 20px;
        background-color:red;


        }
    .clearfix{
        clear:both;
    }
    footer {
        /*height: 50px;*/
        text-align: center;
        position:absolute;  
        border:1px solid red;
    }
```

**html**

```
<div id="columns">
        text
    </div>
    <div id="columns">
        text
    </div>
    <div id="columns">
        text
    </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using any floated items, the default behavior is for them not to count towards other content in that area, so they'd appear to one side of other content.

Of course, if you want to prevent that, the `clear` property will essentially continue below any floated items on one (or either) side before it.

```
footer {
    height: 50px;
    clear: both; /* can also use `clear: left` here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try after removeing `bottom:0;` and put below html code after third column

```
<div id='footer'>
   <p>Footer Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the css clear for your problem

like `clear :both` for id/class of you div

Answer (score 0):

text

```
<div id="columns">
    text
</div>
<div id="columns">
    text
</div>
```

`<div style="clear:both"></div>` 
`<footer>footer</footer>`